# Is there a way to convert some "|" (not all) into commas in a texfile in linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sed

I have a text file while looks like this:

```
1|Name..........
2|Name........
```

I want it to look like this:

```
1,Name.......
2,Name.......
```

Now the issue is that the name also contains the `|` character sometimes and I don't want to change those.
Is there any way I could change the `|` characters which occur right after an integer?

I tried using `sed` for this but couldn't figure out how to do it.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/).*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace first `|` with `,`:

```
sed 's/|/,/' file`
```

Answer (score 0):

use simple `awk` for it too.

```
awk '{sub("|",",")} 1' Input_file
```

***Explanation of above code:*** Using `sub` utility of `awk` which does the substitution of regex provided to it in a line/variable. It's patter is `sub(source_value,new_value,line/variable)`. Then providing `1` means I am making condition here TRUE for `awk` and NOT mentioning any action to happen so by default action will happen which is printing of the current line.

In case you want to save the changed inside Input_file itself then use following.

```
awk '{sub("|",",")} 1' Input_file > temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file
```